# MongoDB Yii and the URL Manager

Tags: php, mongodb, yii

I'm having a bit of trouble with MongoID in and the url manager in Yii.

If I have a url like:

```
http://www.example.com/article/1
```

or

```
http://www.example.com/article/view/1
```

Everything works. Now for the problem. I am using MongoDB so my urls look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/article/50e18c655b0c4dce75000033
```

or

> http://www.example.com/article/view/50e18c655b0c4dce75000033

And each scenario throws a 404 not found error, like it cannot go the actionView. My url manager in the config looks like this:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<cid:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
```

What am I doing wrong with this and how do I get the MongoID to register as ids?

Comment: `\d+` matches decimal digits, not hex.

Comment: Hmmm this part I think `<id:\d+>`, it is regex for digit only, try: `<id:\d\w+>` or something

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Im my case it was invite system and it was very important to rule exactly hex, bcause I have InviteController as well.

```
'invite/<invite_key:[a-fA-F0-9-]+>'=>'site/invite',
```

in your case i suppose it should be something like this

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:[a-fA-F0-9-]+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<cid:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
```

Maybe you should change `<id:[a-fA-F0-9-]+>` to `<cid:[a-fA-F0-9-]+>`, I dont really know how your controller works.

I hope you found solution a bit earlier. But Google points here for the several request.